# Inserting multi-language values to sql server from parameter

Tags: stored-procedures

Im trying to insert multi language to the database. But i needed to do it from StoredProcedure. The Value will be set in nvarchar of a parameter. But converting that to unicode with N is not working out for me.

Working Model:

```
declare @kk nvarchar(1000),@K nvarchar(100);
set @k = 'મારું નામ પિનલ છે';<br>
set @kk = N'મારું નામ પિનલ છે';<br>
print @kk;
```

To be fixed:

```
 declare @kk nvarchar(1000),@K nvarchar(100);<br>
 set @k = 'મારું નામ પિનલ છે';<br>
 set @kk = N''+@k+'';<br>
 print @kk;
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried to set `UTF-8` character set?

Comment: in storedprocedure?